# Override default reducers in SAP Spartacus

Tags: redux, ngrx, spartacus-storefront

Is there a way to override default reducers in a Spartacus project?

For example i want to change the way the cart state is returned for certain cart action.

And is it possible to add some fields to the state ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the following thread, you might find it useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427913/extend-spartacus-ngrx-store-with-additional-data

Comment: You can use type augmentations to extend the built-in spartacus models https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/type-augmentation. Also, could you be more specific about your use case?